# Need help in finding the root cause in this wrong batch command

Tags: command-line, batch-file

```
IF %processor_architecture% == AMD64 (SET querypath=hklm\software\x) ELSE (SET dsetquerypath=hklm\software\y)

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=\" %%G IN ('REG QUERY "%querypath%" 2^>NUL') DO ECHO %%G
```

Let me explain what im trying to accomplish out of this batch command.
Basically there is a tool which gets intalled on hklm\software\x(on 32bit windows) and  hklm\software\y(on 64 bit windows).

I need the exact path of the software from registry.Which could tell me whether the machine is 32 or 64 bit and take appropriate action. But right now every time I using this batch command it is always returning path as hklm\software\y.

I don't know WHY?
That is what I need help to make this batch file right.

Comment: You could also just use WMI to find out whether you're on 32 or 64 bit Windows. Which is actually more reliably than this.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have enough time to change the way it is working right now(using batch commands).Because it is in QA period and soon to go into production.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I think [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/HOWTO-Detect-Process-Bitness.aspx) may provide an explanation and solution to your problem, and in batch too :)

The spaces around the `==` may be causing your problem.

You're actually comparing the value of `%processor_architecture%[space]` to `[space]AMD64`

Try:

```
IF %processor_architecture%==AMD64...
```

If Command Extensions are enabled you can also do:

```
IF /I %processor_architecture% equ AMD64
```

(the `/I` switch makes the IF case insensitive)

Comment: I just tried that, It is still giving me the same path for 64 bit machine

Comment: @alice7: Did you clean up the errors in your code snippet above, or are they typos? Do you know for sure the `%processor_architecture%` environment variable will contain "AMD64", or is it always "x86"? Johannes Rossel's suggestion to use WMI may be the way to go.

Comment: Yes they are typos.I don't know, it is a environment variable so it says AMD64 for x64 bit machine but it says x86.

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected if AMD64 is quoted:

```
set processor_architecture="AMD64"
IF %processor_architecture% == "AMD64" (SET querypath=hklm\software\x) ELSE > (SET  querypath=hklm\software\y)
echo querypath=%querypath%
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
ECHO processor_architecture="%processor_architecture%"
SET querypath=hklm\software\y
IF "%processor_architecture%" == "AMD64" SET querypath=hklm\software\x
```

Also note you have some typos on your `ELSE` part; isn't the problem there?

Comment: looks like %processor_architecture% is always returning x86 even on 64 bit machine.

Comment: well, if you could search registry twice, you can look for one path and, if don't find anything, search another one

Answer (score -1):

I think you are falling victim to the phenomenon where the variables are expanded/evaluated as soon as they are read.  There is a good discussion of that at [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx).

Also search on "immediate expansion" and "delayed expansion".

Comment: Delayed expansion is not always the answer when environment variables are involved ...